# Get error stating "Need to run version 1.7.2 manually at least once" when installing Minecraft Forge using Java

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've followed the instructions on this site for downloading and installing minecraft forge version 1.7.9 but when Java tries to install the files I get an error that I "need to run version 1.7.2 manually at least once." What does this mean, I've opened and played the game several times.

Comment: Are you installing the mods to a separate profile?  Forge needs a place to put the java files, so unless you're modding an existing profile (bad idea), that place doesn't exist yet.

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: Working on it now, will let you know what happens.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I think I have 2 problems

Comment: 1. I have no idea what I'm doing and 2. I'm trying to install the Forge for version 1.7.2 and the game version I have is 1.7.9. it appears there is no Forge for 1.7.9 yet.

Answer (score 7):

When installing forge you need to run the version that you are modding first and THEN install forge. So if I am going to mod 1.7.2 I would first run it normally and THEN install forge.

Answer (score -3):

Run 1.7.2 at least once before you install it.

Comment: This looks like a comment o.o